# How to backgroundColor key values are map in reactjs?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I need to specify not in array values one Buttons should be in another color using a value in the **map** .
 Is it any possible? I attached my code below.
[CodeSandbox box Code](https://codesandbox.io/s/sleepy-darwin-4po149?file=/src/App.js)

Comment: Please read [Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/125997/something-on-my-web-site-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it). Questions that depend on external resources to be understood become useless when the external resource goes away or is fixed. Create a [MCVE] and put it in **the question itself** instead. Stackoverflow does support [inline live demos](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/16/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use some function and check if index is available in queue, show red else blue.

```
export default function App() {
  var b = ["one", "two", "three", "soma"];
  var que = [1, 2, 3];
  return (
    <div className="App">
      {b.map((text, index) => (
        <>
          <button
            style={{
              backgroundColor: que.some((value) => value === index + 1)
                ? "red"
                : "blue"
            }}
          >
            Button
          </button>
        </>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Better solution:

```
export default function App() {
  var b = ["one", "two", "three", "soma"];
  const set = new Set([(1, 2, 3)]);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      {b.map((text, index) => (
        <>
          <button
            style={{
              backgroundColor: set.has(index + 1) ? "red" : "blue",
            }}
          >
            Button
          </button>
        </>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you want to implement like this.

```
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  var b = ["one", "two", "three", "soma"];
  var que = [1, 2, 3];
  return (
    <div className="App">
      {b.map((text, index) => (
        <>
          <button
            style={{
              backgroundColor: que.filter((value) =>
                value === index + 1).length ? "red" : "blue"
            }}
          >
            Button
          </button>
        </>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}
```

This is codepen URL
https://codesandbox.io/s/sleepy-darwin-4po149?file=/src/App.js:0-415

Comment: i need only in map value and ternary condition also

Comment: ah, I misunderstand.
I have changed my code.

Comment: ya now code is working

Comment: @EtsukoSusui no need for a filter, the Filter is slower. You can solve this using some.